# Type/casting of compound assignment operators? (such as *= (star-equals))

Tags: c++, casting

I am confused as to this part of exemplary code:

```
float f = 3.01;
int i;
```

- Case 1: `i = f * 100;    // i == 300`
- Case 2: `i = f *= 100;   // i == 301`

I've no idea why in first case the decimal part gets "lost".
I've also tried:

```
(double) f * 100
f * 100.0
```

Then I tried volatile and flags to gcc that turn off all optimization.
The result is still the same.

Can somebody explain to me why does the first case behave so? Thank you.

Comment: Try with this as well: `f = 3.01; f = f * 100; i = f;` I believe that should focus the question more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in type conversion:

```
int i = f * 100 ;
```

is equivalent to

```
double tmp = f* 100.0;
int i = tmp;
```

And the difference with second case is that tmp is `double`! And yes, there is a case, where double is "less precise"

To illustrate this, I wrote the follwing program:

```
int main()
{
    float f = 3.01;
    float mf = f * 100;
    double md = f * 100;

    int if_ = mf;
    int id = md;

    std::cout << f << ' ' << mf << ' ' << md << ' ' << ' ' << (mf - md) << ' ' << if_ << ' ' << id << '\n';
}
```

**Edit:**

On my system I get same result for my `gcc 4.6.1` and `cl 16.00` (`MS VS 10`):

```
3.01 301 301  9.53674e-007 301 300
```

**Edit2**

Found, that enabling optimization `-O2` eliminates issue. This explains difference with IDEONE.

Here is another code:

```
int main()
{
    float f = 3.01;
    float mf = f * 100;
    return mf + (f*100);

    //std::cout << f << ' ' << mf << ' ' << md << ' ' << ' ' << (mf - md) << ' ' << if_ << ' ' << id << '\n';
}
```

And its assembly with `-O0`

```
    movl    $0x4040a3d7, %eax
    movl    %eax, 28(%esp)


    flds    28(%esp)
    flds    LC1
    fmulp   %st, %st(1)
    fstps   24(%esp)
    flds    28(%esp)
    flds    LC1
    fmulp   %st, %st(1)
    fadds   24(%esp)
    fnstcw  14(%esp)
    movw    14(%esp), %ax
    movb    $12, %ah
    movw    %ax, 12(%esp)
    fldcw   12(%esp)
    fistpl  8(%esp)
    fldcw   14(%esp)
    movl    8(%esp), %eax
```

We can see only one explicit conversion to single precision instruction (`fspts`). This conforms my guess, that temporary evaluates from `double`, not `float`.

And with `-O2` assembly is pretty simple:

```
    movl    $602, %eax
```

**And at last**

If we disable optimization of evaluting, I[DEONE compiler reproduce behavior too](http://ideone.com/xIE4j):

Comment: Your output: http://ideone.com/yokdY -- Your program doesn't really show what it is supposed to, does it? ;)

Comment: @cooky451, Seems to be platfrom dependend: gcc 4.6.1 & cl 16.00 reproduces original error. Will edit post in a minute

Comment: Your point seems strange anyway, since the expression f * 100 is float, not double. Try this: http://ideone.com/andfC If it gives "d" or "double" on your system, we have the reason.

Comment: Interesting. n3242 4.6/1 -> "A prvalue of type float can be converted to a prvalue of type double. The value is unchanged." Which basically means that the compiler can do whatever he wants at this point, if it is allowed for pure rvalues, you cannot even cast to be sure.

Comment: I kind of don't think this is a bug according to the standard, since the standard allows the conversion at any point. But it seems indeed odd to allow this.

Comment: @cooky451, standard claims that 'The value is unchanged'. Anyway, I replaced with 'behavior'

Comment: Obviously they do not regard cast as the change in value. All of this is kind of fuzzy, I guess it should not be allowed. Anyway, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that in the first example, the temporary result has higher accuracy than float and the result is almost 301 (e.g. 300.999999999999). In the second example the result is put into f (which is a float) and is rounded to 301.

I'm not sure about that but it seems like a fair guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your second case you take f, which is a float and multiply it by 100, which equals 301, then you put that value into your int i, there is no decimal place so there is no loss of data.

Comment: Yes and this is what I've expected. I am confused why the temporary result (even with an explicit cast) does not behave in the same manner.

Comment: I've just tried it out myself and I believe in case one, the compiler is taking the float value, and turning it into an int BEFORE multiplying 100 by it, so it turns out to be 300.

Comment: If you modify your case 1 to this line: i = abs(f * 100); it works, abs returns the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler bug? It works fine here: http://ideone.com/FlQCL